# how to get selected text from iframe with javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, selected

```
<html>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function smth() {

    if (document.getSelection) {
    var str = document.getSelection();
    if (window.RegExp) {
      var regstr = unescape("%20%20%20%20%20");
      var regexp = new RegExp(regstr, "g");
      str = str.replace(regexp, "");
    }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
     var range = document.selection.createRange();
     var str = range.text;
    }   

    alert(str);
   }
  </script>   

    <iframe id="my"  width="300" height="225">
   .....some html ....
    </iframe>      

    <a href="#" onclick="smth();">AA</a>
 </body>    
</html>
```

with `smth` function i can get selected text from some div, but it doesnt work with iframe.
any ideas how to get selected text from iframe ?

Answer (score 18):

> document.getSelection

Is on the outer document. To get the selection of the document in the iframe you need to grab the inner document:

```
var iframe= document.getElementById('my');
var idoc= iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; // ie compatibility

idoc.getSelection()
```

Note however that WebKit does not support `document.getSelection()` *or* `document.selection`. Try replacing it with `window.getSelection()` which works in both Firefox and WebKit, but returns a selection object (a collection/wrapper around Ranges), which needs stringing:

```
var idoc= iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var iwin= iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.defaultView;

''+iwin.getSelection()
```

I'm not sure what the point of this is:

```
if (window.RegExp) {
  var regstr = unescape("%20%20%20%20%20");
  var regexp = new RegExp(regstr, "g");
  str = str.replace(regexp, "");
}
```

`RegExp` is basic JavaScript dating back to the very earliest version; it will always be there, you don't have to sniff for it. The URL-encoding of multiple spaces is quite unnecessary. You don't even need RegExp as such, a string replace could be written as:

```
str= str.split('     ').join('');
```

Comment: window.getSelection() returns a selection object, not a Range. toString on the selection will give you the selection text though.

Comment: Yep, `''+` is an idiom for toString.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was correcting a minor error in your referring to the selection object returned from window.getSelection() as a Range but agreeing with you that your code would work.

Comment: Oh! yes, I see what you mean. will fix, ta!

Comment: I was getting contentWindow undefined for iframe. It seems the right way to get window for iframe is using 'window.frames'. window.frames[0].getSelection() gives me what I was looking for

Answer (score 11):

You need to get the selection from the document/window in the iframe.

```
function getIframeSelectionText(iframe) {
  var win = iframe.contentWindow;
  var doc = win.document;

  if (win.getSelection) {
    return win.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (doc.selection && doc.selection.createRange) {
    return doc.selection.createRange().text;
  }
}

var iframe = document.getElementById("my");
alert(getIframeSelectionText(iframe));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't access data inside an `iframe` that is from a domain different than yours.
This is due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: ok , sorry wrong example,  in iframe i have text, i use iframe for wysiwig editor, so it isn't on different domain.

Answer (score 2):

Following code will return the selected text.

```
function getSelectedText(frameId) { 
    // In ExtJS use: 
    // var frame = Ext.getDom(frameId); 
    var frame = document.getElementById(frameId); 

    var frameWindow = frame && frame.contentWindow; 
    var frameDocument = frameWindow && frameWindow.document; 

    if (frameDocument) { 
        if (frameDocument.getSelection) { 
            // Most browsers 
            return String(frameDocument.getSelection()); 
        } 
        else if (frameDocument.selection) { 
            // Internet Explorer 8 and below 
            return frameDocument.selection.createRange().text; 
        } 
        else if (frameWindow.getSelection) { 
            // Safari 3 
            return String(frameWindow.getSelection()); 
        } 
    } 

    /* Fall-through. This could happen if this function is called 
       on a frame that doesn't exist or that isn't ready yet. */ 
    return ''; 
}
```

Hope this will help to someone.

Comment: In firefox in console: Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'". It is in line where is: "var frameDocument = [...]".

Answer (score 2):

This code works in all modern browsers:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('my');
var idoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; // ie compatibility
var text = idoc.getSelection().toString();
```