# selected text in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get a selected text inside a iframe.

I my page i'm having a iframe which is editable true.
So how can i get the selected text in that iframe.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471759/how-to-get-selected-text-from-iframe-with-javascript

Comment: @Dan McG - then down vote it!

Comment: -1. I knew I forgot something...

Answer (score 2):

Ignore what I had wrote, it was garbage.

Here is the real deal:

```
var iframe= document.getElementById('yourFrameId');
var idoc= iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document; // For IE.
alert(idoc.getSelection());
```

The above was blatantly stolen from [bobince's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) answer to [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471759/how-to-get-selected-text-from-iframe-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you mean by selected text but this is how you access the contents of an iframe with jquery

```
$('#iFrameID').contents().find('#whatImLookingFor').text(getSelectedText());

function getSelectedText(){
    if(window.getSelection){
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    }
    else if(document.getSelection){
        return document.getSelection();
    }
    else if(document.selection){
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
}
```

Comment: selected text in the sense (Selected text using mouse)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by editable true for an iframe. May be it is a textfield or textarea. But if you really have an iframe and some text in it is selected then here is a code segment that should work on a number of browsers:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("frame1");
var txt = "";
if (iframe.contentWindow.getSelection) {
    txt = iframe.contentWindow.getSelection();
} else if (iframe.contentWindow.document.getSelection) {
    txt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getSelection();
} else if (iframe.contentWindow.document.selection) {
    txt = iframe.contentWindow.document.selection.createRange().text;
}
```