# Getting selected text within iframe in IE

Tags: javascript

I have iframe with id="iView" and designMode = on.

My code:

```
 var iframeWindow = document.getElementById('iView').contentWindow.document;                                                                                            
 var range = iframeWindow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

The Error I get:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Object doesn't support this property
>   or method

I also tried answers from
   [how to get selected text from iframe with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471759/how-to-get-selected-text-from-iframe-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no getSelection method for the document object in IE, you have to use the selection object instead.

```
var selText;
var iframeWindow = document.getElementById('iView').contentWindow;
if (iframeWindow.getSelection)
    selText = iframeWindow.getSelection()+"";
else if (iframeWindow.document.selection)
    selText = iframeWindow.document.selection.createRange().text;
```

Comment: why there is need to check iframeWindow.getSelection or iframeWindow.document.selection?

Comment: You're checking the functionality exists, which is essentially a browser check.  If the browser doesn't support the method, those statements would return false and the script wouldn't execute - if the checks weren't there and the browser doesn't support the method an error is thrown.  Alternatively, you could use a try/catch statement but this is usually the defacto method of functionality testing.

Comment: @samuel: This is a perfectly good answer but pretty much identical to a couple found in the other question you mentioned (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471759/how-to-get-selected-text-from-iframe-with-javascript), so how has this given you new information?

Comment: lol just checked and it's most identical to your own answer in that question.  Sorry if it seems like I duplicated it (I didn't) :-) +1 for it anyway.

Comment: @Andy E: I wasn't making a particular case for my answer and I didn't think you'd duplicated it because the style's slightly different, but thanks for the upvote :)