# how to get selected text from iframe with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, iframe, getselection

how to get selected text from iframe with javascript ?

Comment: Please add some more information. Is the iframe pointing to a page on your domain?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471759/how-to-get-selected-text-from-iframe-with-javascript

Answer (score 2):

```
var $ifx = $('<iframe src="filename.html" height=200 width=200></iframe>').appendTo(document.body);

$(document.body).bind('click', function(){
     var u_sel;
     if(window.getSelection){
        u_sel = ifx[0].contentWindow.getSelection();
      // u_sel.text()   InternetExplorer !!
      alert(u_sel);
     }
});
```

That should do it, as long as the `iframe src` is targeting your own `domain`.
Tested only on `FireFox 3.6.7` so far.

Comment: Also, the `getSelection()` method of a window object returns a `Selection` object, not a string. You need to call `toString()` on it.

Comment: @Tim Down: No need to call `.toString()` since javascript already does the job for you.

Comment: Well yes, if you happen to be alerting it. Won't work so well if, say, you wanted to do a string substitution on it and tried to call `replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIframeSelectionText(iframe) {
  var win = iframe.contentWindow;
  var doc = iframe.contentDocument || win.document;

  if (win.getSelection) {
    return win.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (doc.selection && doc.selection.createRange) {
    return doc.selection.createRange().text;
  }
}

var iframe = document.getElementById("your_iframe");
alert(getIframeSelectionText(iframe));
```

As noted by jAndy, this will only work if the iframe document is served from the same domain as the containing document.