# jQuery : How to fill the input form automatically from text on webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I have a project to filter 100k-200k of websites to gather the website's owner's name and emails, by viewing it on iframe. What I really need is if I click/select the name on the website I reviewed, it filled the name input form automatically, and the same for emails.

Anybody know the solution? Any response will be appreciated.

*if you need my code, just tell me and I will put it here. It's only an html page with `<iframe>` and `<form>`, though.

Here`s the code:

```
<div class="container container-harvester">
  <div class="harvester-form">
    <%= form_for(:harvesters, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
        Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
        Email: <%= f.text_field :email %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :website, :value => "", :class => "website-harvester" %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :skipped, :value => "true" %>
        <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => "btn btn-primary submit-harvester", "data-disable-with" => "Saving..." %>
        <a href="#" class="delete-website btn btn-danger" data-id="">Delete</a>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="harvester-iframe">
    <iframe name="harvester-iframe" data-id="<%= @websites.first.id %>" src="<%= @websites.first.url %>" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="harvester-link">
    <ul>
      <% @websites.each do |w| %>
        <% unless @registered.collect(&:website).include?(w.url) %>
          <li><a class="" href="<%= w.url %>" target="harvester-iframe" data-id="<%= w.id %>"><%= w.url %></a></li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<% content_for :unobtrusive_js do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('.harvester-link a').on('click', function (e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href')
          , id = $(this).attr('data-id')
          , $el = $(e.currentTarget);
        $('.harvester-iframe iframe').attr('src', url);
        $('.harvester-iframe iframe').attr('data-id', id);
        $('.website-harvester').attr('value', url);
        $('.delete-website').attr('data-id', id);
        $('.submit-harvester').attr('data-id', id);

        $('.harvester-link a').removeClass('active');
        $el.addClass('active');
      });
      $('.harvester-iframe iframe').on('load', function (e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('src')
          , id = $(this).attr('data-id')
          , $el = $(e.currentTarget);
        $('.delete-website').attr('value', url);
        $('.delete-website').attr('data-id', id);
        $('.website-harvester').attr('value', url);
        $('.submit-harvester').attr('data-id', id);
      });
      $('.delete-website').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        API.delete(Routes.harvester_website_path(id)).done(function (response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      })
      $('.submit-harvester').on('click', function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        API.delete(Routes.harvester_website_path(id)).done(function (response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      })
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: On click, grab the `option` value, send an AJAX request for the info, retrieve, sort the JSON to the form in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is the same origin policy of Javascript (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). So you have to get the content from that side to your server e.g. with PHP `file_get_contents()`. So you could display in your iframe this php and as a get the url.

```
<iframe src="get_content.php?url=THE_URL"></iframe>
```

and your get_content.php could look like this:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents( $_GET["url"] );
?>
```

To get the content you select in this iframe, this solution might help:
[how to get selected text from iframe with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324959/how-to-get-selected-text-from-iframe-with-javascript/3326710#3326710)

The iframe might not look like its origin, but should work most of the times fine.

To automatically seperate, if you have now selected the name or the email, take a look at Javascript Regular Expressions and especially the `match()`-Function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Hope, this helps.