# Pass the querystring value and fill into textbox with Jquery not work

Tags: jquery

On a web page there is a textbox. I would like to pass the value from querystring and fill into the textbox.

I have a jQuery function successfully capture the querystring value. Here is the jQuery code I tried to fill into the textbox:

```
$(function() {
    var keyword = getParameterByName('k');
    alert(keyword);
    $("#SearchBox input:text").eq(0).val(keyword);
});

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Above code works fine. However, if I remove the line `alert(keyword)`, the textbox will not be filled. If I move the `alert(keyword)` to the end of function the textbox will not be filled, too.

Why is that? I cannot think of any reason an alert line will influence the outcome. Please give me some idea. Thank you!

Comment: share the method definition for `getParameterByName`

Comment: Is the `#SearchBox input:text` element being loaded by AJAX, or otherwise appended to the DOM after the page is loaded? Does `getParameterByName()` use asynchronous functions?

Comment: function GetQueryStringParams(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​

Comment: Rory, I am not sure. I am editing SharePoint's search center default page.

Comment: Your function is named `GetQueryStringParams` yet you call `getParameterByName` ...?

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964629/javascript-function-not-working-without-alert very close to my problem. But I don't know how to apply on my code.