# getSelection does not return selected text - ie11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-11

I am not sure why the `getSelection` method is not returning me the selected text. What I have is a reference to an iframe object where I call its' `contentwindow` property and then use that to find another iframe inside that iframe.

```
var iFramed = i.contentWindow.frameElement
```

when I do a `console.log(iFramed)` I get the iframe and see that it is correct, but when I do `console.log(iFramed.contentWindow.getSelection())` and `console.log(iFramed.contentDocument.getSelection())` the selection object I get back is empty, and I know that there are selected text. Any insight as to why? This is a special case that I am doing for IE11.

Here is what`console.log(iFramed)` looks like

[image]

here is what the selection object look like

[image]

**Update**

I focused the iframe and is now able to get the entire body in the selection object, but I am still not able to get the selected text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471759/how-to-get-selected-text-from-iframe-with-javascript

Comment: @EricBlade yeah I saw that too and that is actually how I found out about `contetnWindow` and `contentDocument`